# Adding each element of a vector to each element of another vector to come up with a vector of sums

Tags: r

hi i have the following vectors in R language x<-c(1,2,3) and y<-c(1,2,3) how do i add each element of x to each element of y to come up with array of 9 resaults i.e resaults (2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outer` to do all the pairwise additions. That normally returns a matrix, you just need to convert it to a simple vector.

```
as.vector(outer(x,y,`+`))
# [1] 2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sapply()` with `+` here, although it's a bit slower than `outer()`

```
> c(sapply(y, `+`, x))
# [1] 2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 x+rep(y,each=length(x))
 #[1] 2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6
```